# Pdf file downloaded from database but i can't Open it , "Failed to load PDF document." error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, pdf, visual-studio-2012

I am using MSSQL, asp.net, Visual Studio 2012. I am writing a code that saves/retrieve pdf files from and into database.

I am saving the files successfully but when I want to download them, it got downloaded but error opening the file as if it got interrupted while downloading. But .txt files are opening successfully, only the pdf files not working.

The code for retrieving the pdf file from database is here:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select Name,Extn,Content from Books where Name=@Name", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.ToString());
SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Clear();

    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = dr["Extn"].ToString();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dr["Name"].ToString() ); // to open file prompt Box open or Save file  
   Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName);
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Content"]);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();


Response.End(); }}
```

The Gridview has only the Name and Extn of the file, and the Select button is enabled, when I select any of the pdf (through the select button), this method runs (SelectedIndexChanged).

The PDF file got downloaded but I can't open it.

Comment: For consistency, you should use the actual parameter name: `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name"...`

Comment: Still Not working

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.